# Create random versioning with a control group

Tags: sql

I am trying to take a result set and split into three groups of different sizes. I have been looking at ntile, rank, row number but can't figure it out.

I could select top n %. But I would then need the next n%.

I need to split into the following different sized groups. 15%, 42.5%, 42.5%. To create a 15% control group and two versions split equally from the remaining records.

The requirement used to be a 50-50 split and I just used the modulus with row number but not sure if that would work here either.

I could write update statements or a stored procedure to accomplish this but would love to do it in a query instead.

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using? Post some code, does not matter is not working, at least is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the actual solution.

Comment: SQL Server 2012.    Case ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C.CustomerID DESC) % 2 
   When 0 Then Cast('6V2B' As Varchar(500))
   When 1 Then Cast('6V2' As Varchar(500))
  End

Comment: edit your question and add there the code, remember to format using the <code> sinippet

Answer (score 0):

This, or something like it, should do it:

```
DECLARE @TotalRows float

SELECT @TotalRows = count(*)
 from MyTable

SELECT Col1, Col2, ColEtc, Ranking
  ,case
     when Ranking < @TotalRows * .15 then 1
     when Ranking < @TotalRows * .575 then 2
     else 3
   end  Ranking
 from (select Col1, Col2, ColEtc
         ,row_number() over (order by Col1) Ranking
        from MyTable) xx
 order by xx.Ranking, xx.Col1, xx.Col2
```

The two queries could have been combined with a CTE, but that seems overly complex. You'll need to check for fringe-cases specific to your data.

Comment: This is great stuff!  Thank you it looks so simple.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fringe cases.